# JavaScript - Getting Value from switch

Tags: javascript, css

I've made a "switch" UI element using CSS that I really like. It's intended to be used for on/off scenarios. Basically, a fancy checkbox. My switch is defined in html like this:

**html**

```
<label class="switch"><input id="mySwitchCheckbox" type="checkbox" /><span id="switchText>Off</span></label>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.switch > checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    alert('here');
    var isChecked = // what goes here?
    if (isChecked) {
      alert('turned on');
    } else {
      alert('turned off');
    }
  });
</script>
```

My css for this component looks like this:

**css**

```
.switch {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block; 
  margin:1px 0;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:middle
}

.switch input {
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
}

.switch span {
  background-color:#c9c9c9; 
  border-radius:12px;
  border:1px solid #eee;    
  display:inline-block; 
  position:relative;
  height:24px;  
  width:52px;
  -webkit-transition:background-color .33s;
  transition:background-color .33s
}

.switch span:after {
  background-color:#fff;    
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:20%;    
  bottom:1px;
  content:"";
  left:2px; 
  position:absolute;
  top:1px;
  width:24px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow:1px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  -webkit-transition:all .13s ease-out;
  transition:all .13s ease-out
}

.switch input:checked+span:after {
  left:26px;
  border:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow:-2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow:-2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}

.switch input:checked+span {
  background-color:#eee
}

.switch span{
  border-color:#818A91
}

.switch input:checked+span{
  background-color:#818A91
}
```

When a user flips the switch, the `onchange` event gets fired. That gives me access to the properties found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). However, I do not see how I can determine if the switch is on or off. In other words, how do I know if the checkbox is checked or not? I'm trying to keep the implementation generic and not reference IDs because a page will have multiple switches.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: `var isChecked = this.checked`

Answer (score 2):

Look this:

```js
 $('[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
   var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
   console.log('isChecked: ' + isChecked);
   $("#switchText").html(isChecked?'Yes checked':'No checked');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input id="mySwitchCheckbox" type="checkbox" /><span id="switchText">Check-me</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native javascript way

```
var isChecked = this.checked;
```

or the jQuery `.prop`

```
var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
```